# Adapting the background according to screen size android

Tags: android

I'm using the WallpaperManager to display a Bitmap in the background.
I'm using `wallpaperManager.setBitmap(wallPaper);` // wallpaper is a Bitmap of course.

I want to ajust this bitmap to the screen size and to display it in every virtual screen (repeated).

Any tips on that?

Answer (score 0):

This article on the Android Developers' site shows the range of screen resolutions for each density.

I believe the wallpapers have to match the screen resolution and are not stretched. You can see this if, for example, you create a new emulator with a high screen density like 480x854. The default home screen background is centred, with large black bands at the top and bottom.

The WallpaperManager API indicates that you must use a PNG- or JPEG-format image, even if you use the setResource() method — the resource must be a Bitmap and so not a nine-patch or other type of Drawable.

Answer (score 0):

You can detect the density of the device and then set the wallpapers accordingly:

```
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
    switch(displayMetrics.densityDpi){ 
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW: 
            // Wallpaper for small sized devices.
            break; 
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM: 
            // Wallpaper for medium-sized devices.
            break; 
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH: 
            // Wallpaper for big-sized devices.
            break; 
    }
```